# Need to use TkApp backend with matplotlib in Pyzo

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to put a live mass spectrum plot into a program that I am writing.  So far I have a simple GUI that give the program its basic functionality.  I also want it to have a live plot of a mass spectrum, a fairly simple 2D bar chart with about 10,000 peaks.  I'd like the user to be able to zoom and pan around the plot but the default backend of matplotlib is really slow.  I've been reading around and other backends are available and TkApp is recommended.  I also want it to be compatible with tkinter Python 3.3.

When I try to change the backend:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

print(mpl.pyplot.get_backend())

mpl.pyplot.switch_backend('TkAgg')

plot = plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
plt.show(plot)

print(mpl.pyplot.get_backend())
```

Output:

```
C:\pyzo2013c\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py:46: UserWarning: Due to a bug in pyparsing <= 2.0.0 on Python 3.x, packrat parsing has been disabled.  Mathtext rendering will be much slower as a result.  Install pyparsing 2.0.0 or later to improve performance.
  warn("Due to a bug in pyparsing <= 2.0.0 on Python 3.x, packrat parsing "
Qt4Agg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MyPyProgs\Sequencer\spectrum_plot.py", line 7, in <module>
    mpl.pyplot.switch_backend('TkAgg')
  File "C:\pyzo2013c\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 124, in switch_backend
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\pyzo2013c\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 28, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "C:\pyzo2013c\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 11, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
  File "C:\pyzo2013c\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
ImportError: cannot import name _tkagg
```

I'm using the Pyzo package.  A couple of recommendations as fixes are to install python3-matplotlib-tk however it cannot find pyzo as it's a stand alone installation of python so is not in the registry.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this with the help of Almar from the Pyzo community group.  I'm posting it here to help anyone else who might have the same issue.

So the first thing to do is to add pyzo to the registry, this is done by running  pyzo_activate.exe.  The cmd is then opened, I then answered y to all of the questions.

After this I downloaded the compatible version of matplotlib (and also PyQtGraph as it was recomended) and they could be installed as normal and recognise pyzo as the python version.  now when the code from the question is run the following output is produced:

```
C:\pyzo2013c\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py:46: UserWarning: Due to a bug in pyparsing <= 2.0.0 on Python 3.x, packrat parsing has been disabled.  Mathtext rendering will be much slower as a result.  Install pyparsing 2.0.0 or later to improve performance.
  warn("Due to a bug in pyparsing <= 2.0.0 on Python 3.x, packrat parsing "
TkAgg
TkAgg
```

This means that the default backend of matplotlib is now TkAgg.  The pan/zoom controls for plot that is produced are smooth and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

First, it sounds like the Pyzo package is missing the `pyparsing` dependency, so that may be one cause of your speed issues.

Second, from the error message it looks like your `matplotlib` wasn't compiled with Tk support for some reason. You might want to contact Pyzo and see if they're aware of this.

As a workaround, I'd recommend first installing Python from [python.org](http://python.org/download), then visiting Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository. If you haven't already run across it, it's a very large and very up-to-date collection of scientific and other Python modules for Windows, packaged as self-installing `.exe` files. Many of the packages are linked to `NumPy` and `SciPy` compiled with Intel's Math Kernel Library (MKL), which can give significantly better performance in heavy-duty applications. Another nice thing about it is he gives dependency information where needed, so if you visit the [`matplotlib`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) link it shows what other packages you'll need to download as well.

While you're there, I'd highly recommend checking out [`IPython`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ipython), an interactive Python development environment that is just overflowing with features.

Comment: Thanks very much for the swift reply.  I will try informing the Pyzo people and will definitely check out the other options that you have suggested.  Thank you very much :-)